# How to replace jquery attr rel with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, w3c

I would like to make my webpages a w3c valid.so i rectifying the errors step by step to be valid , i used html5 doctype, I found an error

Line 348, Column 81: RDFa Core attribute rel is not allowed on the li element in HTML5 + RDFa 1.1 Lite documents. Consider checking against the HTML5 + RDFa 1.1 schema instead.

so i tried to replaced id instead of rel , w3c valid but the code doesn't work . How to work the below code without using rel?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show(); 
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
});
});
</script> 
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="active" rel="tab2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Reviews&nbsp;&nbsp;</li><li rel="tab3">News</li><li rel="tab4">&nbsp;&nbsp;Articles&nbsp;</li></ul>


<div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="width:326px;">data</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content" style="width:326px;">data tab2</div>
```

Comment: Using JavaScript for fixing the markup doesn't make your document valid.

Comment: The code you posted still has `rel="tab2"`, did you change that to an id and instead use `.attr("id")`?

Comment: I think the wording in the question is throwing this off, It appears as though (based on code) he is not trying to replace `rel` with `id` using javascript, unless he simply did not post that code here.

Comment: i tried to replace rel with id , active tab only worked ,other tabs does't works it shows blank

Comment: If you just change rel to id, then you have multiple elements on the page with the same id, which is also invalid HTML, and very likely the reason it didn't work properly for you. Change them from rel to id, but also make sure the new id is unique on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Manually (not with Javascript) go through the HTML, find each `<li>` element, and replace `rel` with `id`. Make sure the id is unique on the page. So you will have to change them to something like `liTab2`, `liTab3`, etc.

Then, in your jQuery, replace `$(this).attr("rel");` with `this.id.replace("li", "").toLowerCase();`.

Not entirely sure what else you're looking for in an answer....

Comment: Why do people recommend `$(this).attr("id")` when `this.id` is way simpler and involves two less function calls?

Comment: I don't know...it's the first thing I thought of. There...I fixed it :-)

Answer (score 2):

For all `li` elements assoicated with the tabs, change this:

```
<li class="active" rel="tab2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Reviews&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
```

to:

```
<li class="active" data-target="tab2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Reviews&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
```

And change

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
```

to:

```
var activeTab = $(this).data("target");
```

Note this uses jQuery default behavior in pulling the HTML5 data-* attributes into the dataset for the object.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I prefer the `this.id` approach as well.  Just was keeping my answer in orignal poster's style.

Comment: Problem here is that you now have multiple elements on the page with the same id. When he calls `$("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();`, it will not find the div. It will get the `li` instead.

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes, might be best to use html5 data attributes. I have updated my answer.